# .htaccess simple rewrite rule not working in subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm working on a subdirectory, and want to rewrite ugly file-urls into prettier URLs.

Like:
domain.com/myfolder/myreport.php --> domain.com/myfolder/MyReport/

**Here's what I have:**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule    ^test/?$    index.php    [NC,L]
```

Taken from [here](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

However, it's not working. I've tested every combination of regex I could imagine, nothing worked.

Are there any other potential problems? Is it possible that all rules are ignored/overwritten by a rule in the root directory or something?

The .htaccess IS being used, if I add "test", I get a 500 Error.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try the following,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Oh my god, it's working - thank you! However, when I enter ".../test/", it's redirected to ".../index.php" - is it possible to keep the URL at ".../test/" while actually showing the file?